# LESS / CSS select parent from element declaration

Tags: css, less

Using some libraries such as Modernizr you get into the html tag some classes that distinct browser capabilities, for example if it can't do css transforms the html tag gets the class no-csstransforms.
What i want to do is to write css properties for an element and split them based on an html class, for example :

```
.my-element {

[SomethingThatCanSelectAparent]html.csstransforms & {
        // i can do transforms to this element
}
[SomethingThatCanSelectAparent]html.no-csstransforms & {
  /// whatever you want do for older browsers
}

}
```

I know that i can start from `html.whaterver { .my-element }`but in large websites it will be very annoying

how can i achieve it in a clean way like this?

Answer (score 4):

In SASS and LESS you should be able to accomplish this with an ampersand like this:

```
.your-element {

  color: red;

  html.csstransforms & { color: blue; } 

}
```

And the output of this should be:

```
.your-element { color: red; }
html.csstransforms .your-element { color: blue; }
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, read the question wrong at first and gave an SASS answer BUT however the same should work also in LESS.

Comment: LESS has the same syntax options on the ampersand, see http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/

Comment: Oops, somehow I read the question "LESS / SASS select parent from element declaration". Sorry, will look if LESS has something similar.

Comment: Thanks @Roberrrt . So the same should also work in LESS.

Comment: Wow i tought it was just going to prefix all declarations with .my-element , so code is already working as i posted ... thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

You're right, but your approach is a bit odd.

This is primarly because CSS has no such thing as a `parent` selector, like `<` or something. So you'll have to classically fall down (as CSS is ment to be) which means:

```
// Declaring the top of the DOM first
html.css-transforms {
    // Specific element when DOM has class x
    .my-element {
        // transformations!
    }
}

// And when the HTML has no such thing,
html.no-css-transforms {
    // Give this styling.
    my-element {
        // no transformations :(
    }
}
```

This applies style to `my-element` based on the `html` tag's classes.

It is, however, possible [utilizing the ampersand (&) with LESS.](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/)

```
.my-element {

    html.css-transforms & {
        // Magic css transforming
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that wasn't there yet when I posted this, ouch. It's still the answer to his question, it's not possible in classic CSS.